# Why is my docker login command not respecting the server argument I pass in?

Tags: docker

I have a docker login command I use occasionally `docker login repos.server.com` which has worked fine until recently.

I tried an experiment where I tried a different server in the login (note the /v2/ added to the server arg) - `docker login repos.server.com/v2/`

This failed, which is fine, it was just me trying something out.  However, now, anytime I try to run the original command, without the server that has /v2/ at the end, I get an error, and the response I get indicates it is still trying to hit the version of the server with /v2/.
So where before the original command worked, now I get an exception:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Docker\yaml\AThing>docker login repos.server.com
Authenticating with existing credentials 
Login did not succeed, error: Error response from daemon: Get https://repos.server.com/v2/: dial tcp 123.45.67.890:443: connect: no route to host
```

You can see in that error that it still seems to be trying to hit /v2/, even though that is no longer what I pass in to the command.  Is there some kind of cache or config I should clear to make it respect the original server?

I have confirmed with another colleague that the command I am trying works fine for him

Comment: Well, the only thing that fixed it was to uninstall and reinstall docker desktop... I would still like to know what to do to fix this or even how to troubleshoot it for future reference, but at least I can do stuff again

Answer (score 1):

The `/v2/` is part of the [registry api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#overview). Every request to authenticate to a registry will go to that path on the registry host and doesn't have anything to do with your previous test. It looks like your issue is related to networking access, so I'd start with a `curl -i https://$registry_host/v2/` and make sure you get an expected result, e.g. hitting docker hub:

```
$ curl -i https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io"
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2020 18:37:37 GMT
Content-Length: 87
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

You should see a `Www-Authenticate` header on a good request.

Comment: I get a valid response from the curl command.  401 with a Www-Authenticate, and I also get a 200 response when I pass in user:password.  So it still feels like something that ended up getting stored somehow within docker

Comment: I had to reinstall docker desktop to get past this issue - any suggestions on what that might have been?

Comment: I can't see your screen to see the commands you were running to break things. Best I can do is tell you the assumption the `/v2/` was being saved somewhere based on the error message is a false assumption.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I can say, all I did was try docker login to server, and it was fine. Then immediately after, I tried docker login to server/v2, and it failed with the message above. Then every attempt after that to the original server failed, as though that one bad attempt  to a wrong server messed up some configuration/setting. Supported by the fact that a reinstall fixed it. So I am back to working, but it would be nice to know what the heck was going on.

Comment: Can you reproduce the failure?